# Does Hank Scorpio still control the East coast of America?

Tags: the-simpsons

In the episode ***You Only Move Twice*** after Homer leaves Globex and returns to Springfield, it is revealed that Hank Scorpio seized the East coast of the USA.

[image: Newspaper]

Has it ever been confirmed if Hank Scorpio still holds the East Coast or if the US government have reclaimed it? This can either be in-universe references or an out of universe confirmation from someone in the production team.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NegativeContinuity